# Why are my lists empty after using the split function?

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to separate the **flowers** and the **shrubs** from the given data to two separate lists. Here is my code:

```
data = ["Andromeda - Shrub","Bellflower - Flower","China Pink - Flower","Daffodil - Flower","Evening Primrose - Flower","French Marigold - Flower","Hydrangea - Shrub","Iris - Flower","Japanese Camellia - Shrub","Lavender - Shrub","Lilac- Shrub","Magnolia - Shrub","Peony - Shrub","Queen Anne's Lace - Flower","Red Hot Poker - Flower","Snapdragon - Flower","Sunflower - Flower","Tiger Lily - Flower","Witch Hazel - Shrub"]

flowers = []
shrubs = []

for i in data:
    x=i.split("-")
    print(x)
    if "Shrub" in x:
        shrubs.extend(x)
    elif "Flower" in x:
        flowers.extend(x)
print(shrubs)
print(flowers)
```

The lists **shrubs** and **flowers** show out to be empty. Why??

Comment: Because you have spaces left, as you probably can see when you print `x`.

Comment: You're splitting on just `"-"`, but those strings also have spaces.  So the first string will give you `["Andromeda ", " Shrub"]`. `"Shrub"` is not in that list.  Try splitting on `" - "` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at the second item when you split by the hyphen. You should also use the list `append` method over `extend` so you don't append the sequence of characters.

```
data = ["Andromeda - Shrub","Bellflower - Flower","China Pink - Flower","Daffodil - Flower","Evening Primrose - Flower","French Marigold - Flower","Hydrangea - Shrub","Iris - Flower","Japanese Camellia - Shrub","Lavender - Shrub","Lilac- Shrub",        "Magnolia - Shrub","Peony - Shrub","Queen Anne's Lace - Flower","Red Hot Poker - Flower","Snapdragon - Flower","Sunflower - Flower","Tiger Lily - Flower","Witch Hazel - Shrub"]

flowers = []
shrubs = []

for i in data:
   flower, flower_type = i.split("-")
   print(flower)
   if "Shrub" in flower_type:
       shrubs.append(flower)
   elif "Flower" in flower_type:
       flowers.append(flower)

print("Shrubs")
print(shrubs)
print("Flowers")
print(flowers)
```

It'd be better to use `i.split(" - ")` but you have one entry ""Lilac- Shrub" what won't match that. If that's not just a typo, fix it, then prefer using the `i.split(" - ")` to have cleaner strings.

Answer (score 1):

As Thierry Lathuille pointed out, you have whitespaces left.
Try replacing all whitespaces first:

```
for i in data:
    i.replace(" ", "")
    x=i.split("-")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `strip` method of a Python string to clean your data from unuseful spaces:

```
data = ["Andromeda - Shrub","Bellflower - Flower","China Pink - Flower","Daffodil - Flower","Evening Primrose - Flower","French Marigold - Flower","Hydrangea - Shrub","Iris - Flower","Japanese Camellia - Shrub","Lavender - Shrub","Lilac- Shrub","Magnolia - Shrub","Peony - Shrub","Queen Anne's Lace - Flower","Red Hot Poker - Flower","Snapdragon - Flower","Sunflower - Flower","Tiger Lily - Flower","Witch Hazel - Shrub"]

flowers = []
shrubs = []

for i in data:
    x = [elm.strip() for elm in i.split("-")]

    print(x)

    if "Shrub" in x:
        shrubs.extend(x)
    elif "Flower" in x:
        flowers.extend(x)

print(shrubs)
print(flowers)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
data = ["Andromeda - Shrub","Bellflower - Flower","China Pink - Flower","Daffodil - Flower","Evening Primrose - Flower","French Marigold - Flower","Hydrangea - Shrub","Iris - Flower","Japanese Camellia - Shrub","Lavender - Shrub","Lilac- Shrub","Magnolia - Shrub","Peony - Shrub","Queen Anne's Lace - Flower","Red Hot Poker - Flower","Snapdragon - Flower","Sunflower - Flower","Tiger Lily - Flower","Witch Hazel - Shrub"]

flowers = []
shrubs = []

for i in data:
    x=i.split("-")
    if "Shrub" == x[1].strip():
        shrubs.append(x[0])
    elif "Flower" == x[1].strip():
        flowers.append(x[0])
print(shrubs)
print(flowers)
```

Output

```
['Andromeda ', 'Hydrangea ', 'Japanese Camellia ', 'Lavender ', 'Lilac', 'Magnolia ', 'Peony ', 'Witch Hazel ']
['Bellflower ', 'China Pink ', 'Daffodil ', 'Evening Primrose ', 'French Marigold ', 'Iris ', "Queen Anne's Lace ", 'Red Hot Poker ', 'Snapdragon ', 'Sunflower ', 'Tiger Lily ']
```

That original code didn't e

Comment: But using the strip method only on the second element you still have the spaces on their names...

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the white space in the `split` statement:

```
data = ["Andromeda - Shrub","Bellflower - Flower","China Pink - Flower","Daffodil - Flower","Evening Primrose - Flower","French Marigold - Flower","Hydrangea - Shrub","Iris - Flower","Japanese Camellia - Shrub","Lavender - Shrub","Lilac- Shrub","Magnolia - Shrub","Peony - Shrub","Queen Anne's Lace - Flower","Red Hot Poker - Flower","Snapdragon - Flower","Sunflower - Flower","Tiger Lily - Flower","Witch Hazel - Shrub"]

flowers = []
shrubs = []

for i in data:
    x=i.split(" - ")
    print(x)
    if "Shrub" in x:
        shrubs.extend(x)
    elif "Flower" in x:
        flowers.extend(x)
print(shrubs)
print(flowers)
```